# SymPy -- define domain of variable

Tags: python, sympy

I'm writing a program to compute an exact differential for my physics laboratory. I know that I can set real domain or positive (`from sympy import *`):

`x, y, z = symbol('x y z', positive = True)`

My problem is to specify domain for example `n>1`. Is it possible?
In my output I'm getting an expresion like `|n^2-1|` and with setting this domain `n>1` I would accept output like `n^2-1` (without absolute value "||")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For assumptions on symbols, you can use *positive* or *negative*:

```
p = Symbol('p', positive=True)
```

But this can only define *p>0* (or *p<0* if you use *negative=True*).

For more complex expression refinement, try *refine(expression, assumption)*:

```
In [1]: n = Symbol('n')

In [2]: refine(Abs(n-1), Q.positive(n-1))
Out[2]: n - 1

In [3]: refine(Abs(n-1))
Out[3]: │n - 1│
```

That is, you create the assumption *Q.positive(n-1)*, that is *n > 1*, and pass it to *refine*.

There is currently work in progress to port this assumption style to other algorithms, but support is still incomplete (*simplify* appears not to recognize this kind of assumption).

It is expected that support of *Q.statement( ... )* will be extended in future versions of SymPy, as there is currently a lot of work in progress on this.