# Define custom domain of a variable in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

I have a real variable `x`, which has a domain between `[0,1]`. How can I achieve that with SymPy?

Context: I want to calculate Hessian of a symbolic function (say `f(x,y)`). I want to see if that Hessian is positive semidefinite over the domain of the variables `x,y`.

Comment: [As of October 2015, it doesn't seem to have been possible.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33216750/sympy-define-domain-of-variable)

Comment: You could refine an expression under the assumption that `x` is in the interval `[0, 1]`, but it doesn't look like you can bake the domain into the symbol itself.