# Sympy - Simplify expression within domain

Tags: sympy, simplify

Can Sympy automatically simplify an expression that includes terms like this one:

```
cos(x)/(cos(x)**2)**(1/2)
```

which can be simplified to `1` in the domain that I am interested in `0 <= x <= pi/2` ?

(Examples of other terms that could be simplified in that domain: acos(cos(x)); sqrt(sin(x)**2); sqrt(cos(2*x) + 1); etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the functions that are in your expression (such as `sin`, `cos` and `tan`), you can do the following according to this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33216750/sympy-define-domain-of-variable):

```py
from sympy import *

x = symbols("x", positive=True)
ex = cos(x)/(cos(x)**2)**(S(1)/2)
ex = refine(ex, Q.positive(sin(x)))
ex = refine(ex, Q.positive(cos(x)))
ex = refine(ex, Q.positive(tan(x)))
print(ex)
```

Note that `Q.positive(x*(pi/2-x))` did not help in the process of simplification for trig functions even though this is exactly what you want in general.

But what if you might have crazy functions like `polygamma`? The following works for some arbitrary choices for `ex` according to my understanding.

It wouldn't be a problem if the expression was already generated before by SymPy, but if you are inputting the expression manually, I suggest using `S(1)/2` or `Rational(1, 2)` to describe one half.

```py
from sympy import *

# define everything as it would have come from previous code
# also define another variable y to be positive
x, y = symbols("x y", positive=True)
ex = cos(x)/(cos(x)**2)**(S(1)/2)

# If you can, always try to use S(1) or Rational(1, 2)
# if you are defining fractions.
# If it's already a pre-calculated variable in sympy, 
# it will already understand it as a half, and you 
# wouldn't have any problems.
# ex = cos(x)/(cos(x)**2)**(S(1)/2)

# if x = arctan(y) and both are positive,
# then we have implicitly that 0 < x < pi/2
ex = simplify(ex.replace(x, atan(y)))
# revert back to old variable x if x is still present
ex = simplify(ex.replace(y, tan(x)))
print(ex)
```

This trick can also be used to define other ranges. For example, if you wanted `1 < x`, then you could have `x = exp(y)` where `y = Symbol("y", positive=True)`.

I think `subs()` will also work instead of `replace()` but I just like to be forceful with substitutions, since SymPy can sometimes ignore the `subs()` command for some variable types like lists and stuff.

Comment: Doesn't work if I input e.g. "ex = Abs(sin(x))", which should be simplified to sin(x). Instead, I get "tan(x)*Abs(cos(x))", which is perhaps less simplified.

Comment: @BernardoCosta I updated the answer to work with those sorts of things if you specifically know that you'll only have to deal with pre-chosen functions. I don't think SymPy can currently do much better than that.

Comment: This is a major help for my problem that I now consider solved. Thanks a lot!

Comment: However, something like "ex = Abs(sin(x) + cos(x))" still does not simplify to "sin(x) + cos(x)". So I guess a lot of manual work is still required to cover all cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can substitute for a symbol that has the assumptions you want:

```
In [27]: e = cos(x)/(cos(x)**2)**(S(1)/2) + cos(x)                                                                     

In [28]: e                                                                                                             
Out[28]: 
            cos(x)   
cos(x) + ────────────
            _________
           ╱    2    
         ╲╱  cos (x) 

In [29]: cosx = Dummy('cosx', positive=True)                                                                           

In [30]: e.subs(cos(x), cosx).subs(cosx, cos(x))                                                                       
Out[30]: cos(x) + 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is quite useful but still doesn't solve my problems, considering that if the expression changes slightly, for example to: (cos(x)+1)/(cos(x)**2)**(1/2), then it cannot isolate the "cos(x)/(cos(x)**2)**(1/2)" part and simplify it to 1+1/(cos(x)**2)**(1/2) nor to 1+1/cos(x).

Comment: I tried with `e = (cos(x)+1)/(cos(x)**2)**(S(1)/2)` and it worked. I used `apart(e.subs(cos(x), cosx).subs(cosx, cos(x)))` to get `1 + 1/cos(x)`. Note `S(1)/2` rather than `1/2`

Comment: Again this helps, but there are way too many trigonometric functions I have to simplify (e.g. acos(cos(x)); sqrt(sin(x)**2); sqrt(cos(2*x) + 1); etc.) that can only be simplified within a certain domain of x and things get messy quickly. I assume there is no automatic way to assign a domain to x, other than "negative" or "positive".

Comment: There isn't a general way to express assumption in equalities. It is intended that this should be possible with the new assumptions and something like `refine(expr, (0 <= x) & (x<= pi /2))` but that's not implemented yet.