# Can constraints be put on SymPy symbols that affect simplification process?

Tags: sympy, symbolic-math

**Is there some way of instantiating SymPy symbols so that they are interpreted as being in a specified interval?**

Instantiate two SymPy symbols

`x = symbols('x', real=True)`
`R = symbols('R', nonnegative=True)`

and then take the square root of their squares.  `sqrt(x**2)` correctly returns |x|.  SymPy is smart enough to realize that taking the absolute value of a nonnegative quantity returns that same quantity, so `sqrt(R**2)` returns R rather than |R|.  The difference in behavior traces to `R`'s instantiation as nonnnegative.

Suppose we have a real symbol `theta`.  Then `sqrt(sin(theta)**2)` returns |sin(theta)|.  Is there a way of telling SymPy that the value of `theta` is to lie between 0 and pi, from which nonnegativity of sin(theta) follows?  Would SymPy then return simply sin(theta) in response to `sqrt(sin(theta)**2)` ?

Comment: There isn't currently a way to do this

Comment: There are two workarounds that I have come across but they are not useful in general situations. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62882489/sympy-simplify-expression-within-domain/62978445#62978445).