# how can I tell SymPy that some terms are positive then make SymPy simplify `sqrt(x^2)` to `x` where `x` may be a complicated term?

Tags: sympy

I'm solving the problem is in section **Auxiliary Elements** in Polya's *How to Solve It*:

> Construct a triangle, being given one angle (*A*), the altitude (*h*) drawn from the vertex of the given angle, and the perimeter (*p*) of the triangle.

I get the solution below, and try to verify it by SymPy:

```py
from sympy import *

h, p, A = symbols("h p A", positive=True)
u = sqrt(h * p * p / 2 / (h + h * cos(A) + p * sin(A)))
v = (p - u * u * sin(A) / h) / 2
y = v + sqrt(v * v - u * u)
z = v - sqrt(v * v - u * u)
x = sqrt(y * y + z * z - 2 * y * z * cos(A))
# x, y, z are solutions

# now verify them:
print("x + y + z =", simplify(x + y + z))
```

The expected result should be `x + y + z = p` but the actual output is a bit complicated:

```
x + y + z = (-p**2*sin(A)/2 + (4*p + 2*sqrt(p**4*sin(A)**2/(h*cos(A) + h + p*sin(A))**2))*(h*cos(A) + h + p*sin(A))/4)/(h*cos(A) + h + p*sin(A))
```

Here I notice that `sqrt(p**4*sin(A)**2/(h*cos(A) + h + p*sin(A))**2)` are not simplified to `p**2*sin(A)/(h*cos(A) + h + p*sin(A))` because SymPy doesn't know whether `sin(A)` and `h*cos(A) + h + p*sin(A)` are positive.

How could I set some parameter to `simplify()` method to make SymPy do the reasonable simplification with some condition (e.g. some terms are positive so that sqrt() can be simplified)?

I refer [Sympy - Simplify expression within domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62882489/sympy-simplify-expression-within-domain) but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this would be to make positive symbols for `sin(A)` and `cos(A)` e.g.:

```
sinA, cosA = symbols('sinA, cosA', positive=True)
```

You could use those while simplifying and substitute for them after.

Another way that will work for some cases is to use `refine` e.g.:

```
In [8]: res = simplify(x + y + z)

In [9]: res
Out[9]: 
  ⎛            ⎛  │         sin(A)        │    ⎞                          ⎞
p⋅⎜-p⋅sin(A) + ⎜p⋅│───────────────────────│ + 2⎟⋅(h⋅cos(A) + h + p⋅sin(A))⎟
  ⎝            ⎝  │h⋅cos(A) + h + p⋅sin(A)│    ⎠                          ⎠
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                        2⋅(h⋅cos(A) + h + p⋅sin(A))                        

In [10]: refine(res, Q.positive(sin(A)) & Q.positive(cos(A)))
Out[10]: 
  ⎛            ⎛        p⋅sin(A)           ⎞                          ⎞
p⋅⎜-p⋅sin(A) + ⎜─────────────────────── + 2⎟⋅(h⋅cos(A) + h + p⋅sin(A))⎟
  ⎝            ⎝h⋅cos(A) + h + p⋅sin(A)    ⎠                          ⎠
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                      2⋅(h⋅cos(A) + h + p⋅sin(A))
```